# RouterModule, path paginas navegación Angular[9]. Problema, se concatena la url y se pierde contenido

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente app_routes para configurar las rutas de navegación entre páginas. Todo va bien, pero si recargo la página la url se vuelve a cargar por encima, tal como se ve en la imagen. 
Cuando inicio el servidor, por defecto aparece [image: Cuando inicio el servidor, por defecto aparece]

Cuando recargo el navegador aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si vuelvo a hacer refresh pierdo la página, parece que en cada carga se va concatenando.

El código del componente es el siguiente:

```
            import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
            import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home.component';

            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


            const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [

            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'}    
            ];

            @NgModule({
                imports:[
                    RouterModule.forRoot ( APP_ROUTES, {useHash:false})
                ],
                exports: [ RouterModule ]
            })

            export class AppRoutingModule {}

            export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacer que la página recargue en el mismo sitio en cada refresh de navegador?

Comment: Sólo añade una barra: `/` a tu ruta en la propiedad `redirectTo`, ya que está tomando la ruta completa (`pathMatch: 'full'`) y le está añadiendo `home` y luego te redirecciona, dando el resultado que tienes. En cambio, si le añades la barra: `redirectTo: '/home'` sí que te llevará al destino que deseas. Más información en la [documentación](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#redirectTo). Saludos

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras, sigue igual, no parece que cambie nada colocando /